# Paste inside dataframe - R

Tags: r, paste

In the dataset of InsectSprays there are 72 rows of 6 different sprays and I want to create another column inside this data.frame that will be the paste product of the spary code with its consecutive number (e.g., A_1…A_12, B_1…B_12,…).

I tried with the script below and how can I proceed.

```
data(InsectSprays)
df <- InsectSprays[1:2] 
paste(rownames(df$spray), 1:nrow(df), sep="_")
```

Comment: Did you meant `paste(df$spray, 1:nrow(df), sep="_")` or `with(df, paste(spray, ave(seq_along(spray), spray, FUN = seq_along), sep="_"))`

Comment: I meant the 2nd option, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ave` to create the sequence column

```
df$New <- with(df, paste(spray, ave(seq_along(spray), spray, FUN = seq_along), sep="_"))
```